# How to apply some template to all inputs type of checkbox and radio in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I had wrote some directive to apply template to checkbox and radio. But its required to add class or attribute to the element.

```
.directive('checkbox', function () {
            return {
                restrict: 'C',
                link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
                    elem.wrap('<span class="check"></span>');
                    elem.after('<span class="checkLtr"></span>');
                }
            };
        })
```

**How to add this template without adding/change element, class or attribute to the element?**

Comment: your question is a bit unclear here, but I think you *might* be asking how to automatically apply this directive to every checkbox just by it being declared as a checkbox, the way you might apply styling in a CSS Stylesheet.  Is that what you are trying to do?

Comment: I simply want to apply some wrapper to all checkboxs without changing my existing html, either it can be done through directive or other method.

Comment: right, I'm not really sure that's something that angular can help you with.

Answer (score 1):

You could make your directive replace the checkbox element so that instead of

```
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox">
```

You have

```
<my-checkbox />
```

And your directive code would look something like

```
.directive('myCheckbox', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<span class="check"><input type="checkbox"></span><span class="checkLtr"></span>',
        replace: true,
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
        }
    };
})
```

And if you need to, you could bind a 'checked' value using an isolate scope and manipulate it in the link function.

Comment: Yes i know, but i don't want to change my existing html...want to apply template without changing my html...

Comment: Well, you have to tell the html about the directive somehow... It can't just magically know where you want to apply a directive or not.

Comment: Yes, i understand, is there any other solution instead directives, that do what i mention above.

Comment: Maybe use jQuery to target all checkbox inputs and `addClass()` for your directive? That way you don't change your HTML source code, although the class will be there in your rendered HTML.